# Computed Width in CSS Responsive Table

Tags: css, html-table

I downloaded this code.  It is an ordinary table with some CSS styling.  The column headers and the table cells are perfectly aligned with each other.

There is no width setting in the CSS script. In the "Inspect" pane the setting appears under the "Computed" tab.

I understand that it has to get computed since no width setting is specified, but what is it that causes the column headers to be aligned and the exact same size as the table cells below them?

Thanks in advance.

```css
body {

font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial;
  

font-size: 14px;
  

line-height: 20px;
  

font-weight: 400;
color: #3b3b3b;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-smoothing: antialiased;
background-color: white /*#2b2b2b; */
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  max-width: 800px;
}

   

 .table {
      margin: 0 0 40px 0;
      width: 100%;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      display: table;
    }

@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  .table {
    display: block;
  }
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}
.row:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
   

 

.row.header {
      font-weight: 900;
      color: #ffffff;
      background-color: #ea6153;
    }
.row.green {
  background-color: #27ae60;
}
   

 .row.blue {
      background-color: #2980b9;
    }
   

 @media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
      .row {
        padding: 8px 0;
        display: block;
      }
    }

.cell {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  display: table-cell;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  .cell {
    padding: 2px 12px;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CSS Responsive Table Layout</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">

  <div class="table">

    <div class="row header">
      <div class="cell">
        Name
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Age
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Occupation
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Location
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        Luke Peters
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        25
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Freelance Web Developer
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Brookline, MA
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        Joseph Smith
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        27
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Project Manager
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Somerville, MA
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        Maxwell Johnson
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        26
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        UX Architect & Designer
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Arlington, MA
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        Harry Harrison
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        25
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Front-End Developer
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Boston, MA
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="table">

    <div class="row header green">
      <div class="cell">
        Product
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Unit Price
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Quantity
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Date Sold
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Status
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        Solid oak work table
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        $800
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        10
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        03/15/2014
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Waiting for Pickup
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        Leather iPhone wallet
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        $45
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        120
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        02/28/2014
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        In Transit
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        27" Apple Thunderbolt displays
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        $1000
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        25
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        02/10/2014
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Delivered
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        Bose studio headphones
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        $60
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        90
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        01/14/2014
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Delivered
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="table">

    <div class="row header blue">
      <div class="cell">
        Username
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Email
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Password
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Active
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        ninjalug
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        misterninja@hotmail.com
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        ************
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Yes
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        jsmith41
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        joseph.smith@gmail.com
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        ************
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        No
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        1337hax0r15
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        hackerdude1000@aol.com
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        ************
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Yes
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        hairyharry19
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        harryharry@gmail.com
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        ************
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Yes
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxPTm.png)

Comment: thats the table-layout properties in action, it draws a 2d grid from rows and cells and adapt width and height to the inner content. Width and height will adjust themselves. If width/height are set, it will be acting like min-width and min-height and the table will adjust to the content growing if needed. You can set a fixed width resetting the table-layout property, height cannot be fixed nor the table show a scrollbar. see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

Comment: colspan and rowspan are maybe attributes you want to know about too : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-table-rowspan-and-colspan-in-HTML and probably a tutorial could help you to get familiar with : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_tables.htm **last** table are not meant to be used for layout purpose, display (flex,grid,table,block,...) or  column CSS  are on the other side.

Comment: So, you're saying that this is accomplished with the default table-layout setting'auto'?

Comment: Can you insert the specific settings into the code so I can follow?  If I start an html table from scratch and a CSS script, I won't obtain the same results.  It always requires you to set explicit 'width' settings.

Comment: yes, that's the defaut behavior (width is not needed and table shrinks/expand according to the content inside) , but it comes with subtilities how you use it  : a few examples : https://jsfiddle.net/muqrzpfx/

Comment: They adjust to fit the content, but even though the content is different in each cell their widths are exactly the same!  So, I still don't understand.

Comment: You need to read a bit more the tutorials, do some testing to fully understand untill you master it (a coiuple of hours will do, but take a break in between to let it come easy) read , do some test, read a again and so on. My english is bad enough to confuse you at one point ;)

Comment: It's not your English.  I understand what you're explaining to me about the table-layout settings.  In the example that I provided in my post, there is no explicit table-layout setting there.  So, why is it that the cell widths are identical in each cell with varying content?  Shouldn't there be a 'table-layout: fixed' setting somewhere in the code/script for this to happen?

Comment: ?? a column's width is set from the widest cell standing in it , table are drawn by col and rows together, the biggest cell will set it's row height's, it's column width's  (others will expand to fit in ) and it won't go acrross a col or a row, unless colspan or rowspan is s added , and even then, it will **not** span only part of a row or a column :)

Comment: If you look at the image I just added, though, you will see that the width for all the cells in EACH column are much wider than they need to be to display the contents in each cell.  EVEN the widest cell is wider than it needs to be to display the content in it!

Comment: did you notice you had some paddings set in the CSS ? ;)

Comment: @xsundevil "EVEN the widest cell is wider than it needs to be" - comes from `padding: 6px 12px;` in the CSS for `.cell` ! ;)

Comment: border-spacing , nor border-collapse have been reset either . read the doc :)

Comment: Look at "Maxwell Johnson" in the first column in the first table.  The padding would have to be, I don't know, maybe 150px for the column width to be that big!

Comment: it's there : `.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
   max-width: 800px;
}

.table {
  width: 100%; 
}`i removed the irrelevant css. Going off ;)